# Did anything ever become of the particular Borg resistance movement that was created in the Voyager episode "Unimatrix Zero?"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

ST Voyager "Unimatrix Zero":

> JANEWAY: Well, **Unimatrix Zero may be gone but it looks like the
>   resistance is alive and kicking. With any luck, the Collective may
>   never be the same.**
>
> SEVEN: Korok said he would try to maintain contact, keep us informed.
>
> JANEWAY: Have you heard from your friend?
>
> SEVEN: No. But I don't expect to. Axum's vessel is in a remote sector
>   of the Beta Quadrant. If I ever imply that he was nothing more than a
>   friend, remind me about today.

There was a resistance movement created in the Episode "Unimatrix Zero." Korok and at least one other Borg ship were taken over as part of this movement.

What ever happened to this movement? Did the resistance movement take off and ever do anything? Was there a full blown civil war after this and how did it go?

Comment: I don't like how Axum was supposed to be "patrolling the border of fluidic space", as if that makes any sense -.-

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hear ya, you'd think since it's a dimensional shift the entry point is not determinant in our universe. But then again...lol such is star trek.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Debatable. The Resistance is evidently of sufficient importance that it merits discussion in a future history class about the Borg, [some thirty years after the event](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/722.htm).

> **JANEWAY:** *As they say in the Temporal Mechanics Department, there's no time like the present.*
>
> **CADET:** *In the year 2377, you aided the Borg resistance movement known as Unimatrix Zero.*
>
> **BARCLAY:** *Sounds like someone's been reading ahead.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *I thought you had a question, Cadet.*
>
> **CADET:** *Yes, ma'am. When you informed the Queen that you were going to liberate thousands of her drones, could you describe the look on her face?*

But beyond that we've got very little to go on.

---

Within in the non-canon EU novels, there's vast amounts of (often conflicting) info about the Borg Resistance with entire novels devoted to its antics.

Comment: I haven't watched endgame yet. It's the only ST epidsode or movie that I haven't seen. I'm rewatching Voyager and am in the middle of the 7th season so I should get to it soon.

Comment: @JMFB - You'll enjoy it. It's basically a self-contained movie and a very nice way to wrap up the series.

Comment: Good I look forward to it. I sure hope it's better then that piece of crap final episode of Enterprise. I'm still waiting to hear Archers speech and the signing. I'm still considering writing his final speech as fanfic. I also wasn't a big fan of the final episode of TNG, "Time's Arrow."

Comment: Time's Arrow was the one with Samuel Clements. All Good Things.

Comment: My bad as usual you're right. I didn't like Time's Arrow that much either but after subsequent washings it grew on me. I never really understood those alien beings, how they were out of phase, different time, etc.

Comment: Both Time's Arrow and All Good Things were outstanding though!